# Cakephp saving related model data creating blank record with one field

Tags: cakephp, associations

I've been trying to figure this problem out all morning. Tried some things from other questions, but it either didn't really apply to my situation or didn't work. I have two tables:

**users** = (id,name,username,password,roles,last_edit,language)
**french_translations** = (id, french_clinical_recommendations, french_tradenames, include_drug, french_category, drug_id, user_id)

User hasMany french_translations and french_translations belongsTo User.

When a user adds or edits a french_translation I want it to save the user id in the french_translations table, the field user_id, for that record, and then put the generic name for a drug in the last_edit field in the users table. Right now it creates a new record in each table. In the users table, everything is blank except for the id and last_edit field(Which puts the correct drug name in the field). And the french_translations table has a record with blanks, with the user_id being the same as the blank one created in the users table.

Controller:

```
    function add($id = null) {
    $userid = $session->read('Auth.User.id');
    $drug = $this->FrenchTranslation->Drug->read(
      array(
          'Drug.id','Drug.generic','Drug.ahl','Drug.aap','Drug.rid','Drug.oral','Drug.mw','Drug.clinical_recommendations',
          'Drug.category','Drug.lrc'
      ),
      $id
    );
    $this->set('user',$userid);
    $this->set('drug',$drug);

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
      $french_translation['FrenchTranslation']['id'] = $this->Session->read('id');
            $this->FrenchTranslation->create();
            if ($this->FrenchTranslation->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The french translation has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'drugs','action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The french translation could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        $drugs = $this->FrenchTranslation->Drug->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('drugs'));
    }

    function edit($id = null) {
    //$this->FrenchTranslation->id = $id;
    $userid = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $username = $this->Auth->user('name');
  //$this->FrenchTranslation->user_id = $id;
    $drug = $this->FrenchTranslation->Drug->read(
      array(
          'Drug.id','Drug.generic','Drug.ahl','Drug.aap','Drug.rid','Drug.oral','Drug.mw','Drug.clinical_recommendations',
          'Drug.category','Drug.lrc'
      ),
      $id
    );

    $this->set('drug',$drug);
    $this->set('user',$userid);
    $this->set('username',$username);

        if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid french translation', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->FrenchTranslation->saveAll($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The french translation has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'drugs','action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The french translation could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->FrenchTranslation->read(null, $id);
        }
        $drugs = $this->FrenchTranslation->Drug->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('drugs'));
    }

    function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for french translation', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->FrenchTranslation->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('French translation deleted', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('French translation was not deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

Edit View:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.last_edit',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$drug['Drug']['generic'])); ?>    
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$user)); ?>
```

Comment: When I change saveAll to save, it saves the user_id field correctly, but there isn't a corresponding generic drug name in the users table.

Comment: Really? No one? I've made a little progress, it now puts the user id into the user_id field of the french_translation table, but it still creates a new user.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem,  (only)one blank user gets created in users table unless I delete it.  I'm unable to figure out where is the problem,  i have too many models(so controllers) related to users to test.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, however, I feel like there's a better and more secure, way of doing it. I am using the security component, and a person has to login to see any of the site, so it's probably safe enough.

I simply added a user.id input for the user id, at that point it could find the appropriate user to store the last_edit into. In the controller I have a variable called $userid which gets the current user id using `$userid = $this->Auth->user('id');` and is passed to the view using `$ths->set('user',$userid);` I used that same user id value in the input for the drugs user_id field.

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.id',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$user));//The user ID last edit will be stored in ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.last_edit',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$drug['Drug']['generic']));//The drug edited last by the specified user ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a late answer, but you should never use the view to set secure variables like `user_id`. Instead, you can set these variables in your controller:

```
$this->request->data['User']['last_edit'] = $this->request->data['Drug']['generic'];
```